# How can I get last element of JSON Object without specifying key value?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, object, jsonparser

Here is the data of covid 19 coming from that API: https://data.covid19india.org/v4/min/timeseries.min.json
I want to reach the last element / or **"2020-03-06"** of **"dates"** JSON Object in JAVA / Android Studio.

If anyone can suggest to me that how can I reach the last element of this JSON Object without converting or changing it into JSON Array.

```
"TT": {
"dates": {
  "2020-01-30": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 1
    }
  },
  "2020-02-02": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 2
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 2
    }
  },
  "2020-03-03": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 3
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 6,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-04": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 22
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 25
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 28,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-05": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 2
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 27
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 30,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-06": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 28
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 31,
      "recovered": 3
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you know the size, then convert the JSON object to an Array and then return the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the JSONObject for dates first and then get the last item by getting a JSONArray on its names(keys), since you have an array of its keys now you can get the last item that exist at `arr.length()-1`.
like this:

```
JSONObject dates = jsonObject.getJSONObject("TT").getJSONObject("dates");
JSONArray arr  = dates.names();
String lastDate = arr2.getString(arr.length()-1);
```

from there you can do whatever since you have the needed key.

by the way your JSON is missing some brackets which bugged me for some time

```
{"TT": {
"dates": {
  "2020-01-30": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 1
    }
  },
  "2020-02-02": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 2
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 2
    }
  },
  "2020-03-03": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 3
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 6,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-04": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 22
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 25
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 28,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-05": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 2
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 27
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 30,
      "recovered": 3
    }
  },
  "2020-03-06": {
    "delta": {
      "confirmed": 1
    },
    "delta7": {
      "confirmed": 28
    },
    "total": {
      "confirmed": 31,
      "recovered": 3
    }
 }
}
}
}
```